# Split and replace href

Tags: jquery, function, replace, split, attr

Im trying to split and replace href using a function. The code is simple and straightforward:

html

```
<a href="http://nu.nl">nu.nl</a>
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {   

     function rep() {
         href = $('a').attr('href');
         url = href.split('/');         
         href.replace(url[2], 'cnn.com');
     }

     rep()
 });
```

As you can see Im calling the function in document ready. I tried 'prop' instead of attr with no luck. What am I doing wrong? 
Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JnpMp/8/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use what `replace` returns. If you want to change the href in the `a` element, you might change

```
href.replace(url[2], 'cnn.com');
```

to

```
$('a').attr('href', href.replace(url[2], 'cnn.com'));
```

Now, supposing you may have more than one `a` element, I'd suggest to replace your whole code with

```
$('a').attr('href', function(_, href){
    url = href.split('/');          
    return href.replace(url[2], 'cnn.com');
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/GUdZ7/)

If you prefer, you may also avoid the splitting using a regex :

```
$('a').attr('href', function(_, href){
     return href.replace(/\/\/[^\/]+/, '//cnn.com')
});
```

Comment: Three parameters of attr ?

Comment: @Adil A closing parenthesis was missing.

Comment: Thanks for sticking around, I like the regex part.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define your function inside of document.ready statement

```
function rep(myURL, replaceWith) {
  var arr = myURL.split('/');          
  myURL = myURL.replace(arr[2], replaceWith);
  return myURL;
}

$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('a').attr('href', rep(
                            $('a').attr('href'), 
                            'cnn.com'
                           )
               );
});
```